# Qt 5.x, ODBC (dBase, dbf), Windows, encodings

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, odbc, dbf

The database is a set of dbf files in Windows-1251 codepage (1C 7.7, if you need to know). How do I get a UTF-8 string as a result? Somehow manages to see the desired text in console only, only with a locale: IBM 866

Code example:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=/path/to/database");
db.open(); // Ok
QSqlQuery query = QSqlQuery("select descr from SC84", db);
query.next(); // Ok

// "в•©С”С‡СЋС‚СЌСЋС… С†С…С‹С…С‡СЋ"
qDebug(query.value(0).toByteArray().data());

// if setup locale ...
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866"));

// "Кузовное железо" (i was looking for this russian words!)
qDebug(query.value(0).toByteArray().data());

// "╩єчютэюх цхыхчю"
QMessageBox::information(this, "test as is", query.value(0).toString());

// "тХй╤Ф╤З╤О╤В╤Н╤О╤Е ╤Ж╤Е╤Л╤Е╤З╤О" — what was wrong?
QMessageBox::information(this, "test from DOS-866",
  QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866")->toUnicode(query.value(0).toByteArray().data()));
```

I understand that there is somewhere an implicit conversion. But cannot find a solution!

PS The question is closed. It was hard to guess that the reason recoding "cp1251 as cp866". The problem is that ignored the connection settings in the ODBC DSN string. Attempts to solve with the option "DataCodePage=ANSI" had failed, the option was discarded. But setting this value in the registry under\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\xBase solved the problem immediately...

Comment: Why `query.value(0).toByteArray()`? Isn't it better to convert to `QString` like `query.value(0).toString()`

Comment: Unfortunately, it changes nothing:
`QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
query.value(0).toString(); // ╩єчютэюх цхыхчю
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866"));
query.value(0).toString(); // ╩єчютэюх цхыхчю`

Comment: What do you need to get? Readable russian text or UTF-8?

Comment: QString isn't utf-8? Need QString for further work with the data (internal database etc).

Comment: You could convert the data to Windows 1251 code page (instead of IBM 866). As a result you'll be given readable russian text in ANSI codepage. After that, you can convert it to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Complements the question, the problem was configuring ODBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query results cp1251 encoded as cp866, mangling text. Setup DataCodePage=ANSI" DSN ODBC is ignored. So you need to set the value of the ANSI in registry `\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\xBase`.